# Chrome extension custom cursor

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome-extension, manifest, mouse-cursor

I building an Google Chrome extension that place some IMG tag in sites. This img tag on :hover must show a custom cursor. The extension uses jQuery as its injected core script. I tried the following methods:

**1.**

```
var cursor = 'url('+chrome.extension.getURL('icons/cursor.cur')+')';
$('#myImgId').css({
    'position': 'absolute', 
    'top':'5px',
    'left':'5px',
    'cursor':cursor
});
```

This is the best working. On smaller sites its shows the cursor. On slower loading sites it does not. But on little sites it fails sometimes.

---

**2.**

```
var cursor = 'url('+chrome.extension.getURL('icons/cursor.cur')+')';    
$('<style>#myImgId{cursor:'+cursor+'}</style>').appendTo('head');
```

This did nothing at all.

---

**3.**

In manifest.json I injected the css.

```
"content_scripts": [
{
   "matches": ["http://*/*"],
   "css": ["css/style.css"],
   "js": ["j/c.js", "j/s.js"]
}
```

The css file just had the cursor:url(icons/cursor.cur) as I don't have idea, how to get real url in a css file. This isn't working at all. I think it must work like this, I didn't find reference for this on code.google though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turned out to make it work css rule should be written as: `{cursor:url(...),default;}`

<strike>For your 3rd method try this in css</strike>

```
#myImgId {
 cursor:url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/icons/cursor.cur');
}
```

(doesn't work due to a bug)

Comment: This is near for the truth. By this I found this: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/i18n.html#overview-predefined where I see this: "Note: Content script CSS files can't use predefined messages such as @@extension_id. For details, see bug 39899". So it must work but it have a bug for now.

Comment: @the_nakos I just tried it and it doesn't work. But I made it work by hardcoding extension id and adding `,default` to css: `cursor:url('chrome-extension://abc/icons/cursor.cur'),default;`. Maybe your other solutions would also work with default?

Comment: It works with the first and second method too! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need a Chrome extension for this; it's a standard feature of CSS to be able to change the cursor when moving over elements, including the ability to change it to a custom image.

You should be able to just add something like this to your CSS:

```
.myimage { cursor: url(icons/cursor.gif);}
```

without having to do any scripting at all.

However there are bugs, quirks and implementation differences in this feature in a variety of browsers.

The biggest quirk to know about is that Internet Explorer expects the cursor file to be a .cur file, whereas all other browsers expect a regular image file (eg a .gif). If you want it to work cross-browser, you will need to provide two versions of your icon and use a browser-specific test or hack in your CSS to make it pick the right one.

A very good summary of the CSS `cursor` feature with its quirks and support in various browsers can be found here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/cursor.html

This page also states that "the image is garbled in Chrome". This may be bad news for you, but the test hasn't been updated for a while so that info applies to Chrome 5, so if there was bug there it may well have been fixed by now.

Comment: Well, for a Chrome extension, IE's behavior is irrelevant.

Comment: You missed my point. My extensions places image on every site user visits and that image must have a custom cursor that packed in the extension. Its part of the extension and only the extension generated image must have that cursor. (Thank you for your answer, the link you provided will come in handy I am sure :) )

Comment: @the_nakos - you're right; it does seem I missed what you were trying to do. Sorry about that. Glad you found the info useful all the same though.

Answer (score 0):

To add:

```
var css = 
'<Style id="myCursor">\n'+
' .myClass { cursor: url('+chrome.extension.getURL("Cursors/myCrossCursor.cur")+'), crosshair; }\n'+
'</Style>';
if ($("head").length == 0) { 
  $("body").before(css);
} else {
  $("head").append(css);
}
```

To remove:

```
$("#myCrossCursor").remove();
```

Do not forget to add the .cur file to the manifest:

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
  "Cursors/myCrossCursor.cur",
  ...
```