# Custom Cursor - Google Chrome Extension

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension, cursor

I created a Chrome extension and I need to change the cursor.

I have looked at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612972/chrome-extension-custom-cursor).

Basically, I need to put this CSS somewhere:

```
 cursor:url('chrome-extension:cursor.cur'),default;
```

Where does the above go? In the manifest?

Answer (score 1):

The manifest is where you declare what files you want to use in your content script, so you would put the file name of where that code is located, rather than the code itself. As the thread you linked shows, your `manifest.json` should have an entry like this:

```
"content_scripts": [
{
   "matches": ["http://*/*"],
   "css": ["css/style.css"],
   ...
}
```

and in your `style.css`, you may include any css code. It also may be helpful to look into the `!important` css property, as you are aiming to override css on a page.